# A series whose terms are the products of terms of a geometric and a power series

Tags: summation, power-series, geometric-series

Consider this summation
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i^ab^i}
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are greater than $1$

It can be upper bounded by the geometric series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{b^i}=\frac{1}{b-1}$

In addition, the summation $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i^a}$ is called power series. It converges for $a >1$, but there is no closed form for it.

I am asking if I can evaluate the original summation exactly or not?
Also, if I can get an upper bound closer than the above one or not? Since the above upper bound depends only on $b$

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^a}=\zeta(a)$$ is called the [Riemann Zeta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

Comment: The title should be rather "Looking for a closed form for a certain sum"

Comment: @mvw: Better might be "A series whose terms are the products of terms of a geometric and a power series" or perhaps simply "Looking for $\sum\frac1{n^ab^n}$"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking at is called the [Polylogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm):
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^ab^n}=\operatorname{Li}_a\left(\frac1b\right)
$$